# Left join in tabular model

Tags: left-join, dax, tabular

I have 2 tables as below.

```
BILLING
AccountId   RatingDate                  Load
1280582     2018-01-04 15:20:13.000     130.000
421947      2018-01-04 11:44:58.000     176.000
1033717     2018-01-04 10:52:23.000     234.000

RATING
AccountId   RatingDate                  RatingMethod
1280582     2018-01-04 15:20:13.000     A
421947      2018-01-04 11:44:58.000     A
1033717     2018-01-04 10:52:23.000     A
```

I need to create a measure in Billing table to calculate the sum of Load column. I have the SQL query to perform the same but I am not able to create the measure with the same logic.

```
SELECT SUM(b.Load) 
FROM Billing b
LEFT JOIN Rating r
ON b.AccountId = r.AccountId
AND b.RatingDate = r.RatingDate                               
WHERE r.RatingMethod = 'A'
```

Can someone help me with the dax formula for creating the measure?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to approach this including

1. Do the left join in the query editor.
2. Create bridge tables or unique indexing columns to relate your two tables.
3. Write a measure using the `LOOKUPVALUE` function.

If you're doing a bunch of other stuff, you'll probably want to consider option #1 or #2, but for just this particular measure, I'll show you #3.

```
LoadSum = CALCULATE(SUM(Billing[Load]),
                    FILTER(Billing,
                           LOOKUPVALUE(Rating[RatingMethod],
                                       Rating[AccountID], Billing[AccountID],
                                       Rating[RatingDate], Billing[RatingDate])
                           = "A"))
```

The above sums over the `[Load]` after filtering rows where `[RatingMethod] = "A"` in the `Rating` table (and matching on the ID and date columns).

---

For #1, select your `Rating` query and click Merge Queries (Home tab).

Select the columns you want to join one (Ctrl+Click in the same order on both of them). Keep the default Left Outer Join and hit OK.

[image: Merge Queries]

Once they're merged, you'll have a new column named `Billing`. Click the expand icon in the top right corner of the column and select which columns you want to expand (select `Load` only).

Once expanded, your table should look like this:

```
RATING
AccountId   RatingDate            RatingMethod  Load
1280582     2018-01-04 15:20:13   A             130
421947      2018-01-04 11:44:58   A             176
1033717     2018-01-04 10:52:23   A             234
```

Comment: hi Alexis can you please provide a sample for option 1 using left join in the query editor?