# Excel formula to find unique values in column A not found in column B and list the values in column C

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns, ColumnA, ColumnB, and ColumnC. I'd like a formula to list all unique values found in ColumnA that are not found in ColumnB.

I have created a formula based on some [reference](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/06/16/extract-an-unique-distinct-list-from-two-columns-using-excel-2007-array-formula/) that does the job, but I think it's rather inelegant. Is there any more elegant solution?

Example of ColumnA, ColumnB, and ColumnC with values

[image]

```
ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC
A        A        D
A        C        B
B        E
B        F
D        G
         A
         H
         C
```

And here is my formula in cell C2, copied down ColumnC:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/((COUNTIF(ColumnB,ColumnA)+COUNTIF(C$1:C1,ColumnA))=0),ColumnA),"")
```

The formula creates two arrays using COUNTIF that check for matches between ColumnA and ColumnB, and between ColumnA and previous entries in ColumnC. Because I'm looking for non-matched entries, I sum the arrays and then use a cool LOOKUP trick to output the last match in the array.

My particular use case involves an existing column (ColumnA) and a new column (ColumnB). I need to create a list of additions and subtractions. The formula above is for subtractions. I can create a formula for additions by swapping ColumnA and ColumnB.

I'd like to keep this formula as a non-array formula, and not use VBA.

Comment: If you don't want ugly formulas for this, then you a better tool like Power Query. See here for a similar problem (the Left Outer Join part): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785583/left-join-in-tabular-model/48793663#48793663

Comment: The formula you have will return results backwards (bottom first to top last).  Here's a formula that will return them in the expected order of top first to bottom last: `=IFERROR(INDEX(ColumnA,MATCH(1,INDEX((COUNTIF(C$1:C1,ColumnA)=0)*(COUNTIF(ColumnB,ColumnA)=0),),0)),"")`.  Either way, that's about as simple as the formula solution is going to get.

Comment: @tigeravatar Thanks! Not having the direction flipped is extremely useful to me.